# XHTML is being modified incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-translator

My assumption would be that when (X)HTML is being translated. That no changes are being made to it.

In my document I have a CSS referenced like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/custom-style.css" />
```

And what the Translator Text API returns within the document is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/custom-style.css">
```

So it removes the self-closing tag which leads to post-processing issues and obviously one does not want to add those cases to certain replacement/fixing steps (dirty/hard to maintain/etc.).

Comment: _My_ assumption would be that translation does not happen by performing string operations on the HTML source code you give the API, but that a proper DOM parser gets used. And when DOM gets “translated back” to source code, such differences easily occur.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Obviously that is what is actually happening under the covers. But I find this at least arguable. The goal of the process should be to keep as much "as is" as possible. One thing that I forgot to mention is that it is actually XHTML, maybe some declarations are not set appropriately to be recognized as a XHTML document. I will get back here after doing some further research. Either way: This adds additional effort on our end and the solution for this may even result in unwanted behavior in our system.

Comment: If I remember correctly there is a 5k character limit per item. My first shot would have been to simply cut the string at these marks (with little semantic checks, e.g. not cutting in the middle of a sentence) and send it over the wire. By applying DOM parsing this additionally may break my use case here as well.

Comment: was the link tag followed by a </link> tag?

Comment: No, the input was also self-closing.

Comment: I mean in the output.  was your self closing tag in the input converted into an open and close tag in the output.

Comment: No, it‘s like in the question. In: Self-closing. Out: No closing at all.